# Manage photo Library on Facebook Messenger app

Tags: photos, facebook, facebook-messenger

I was just wondering if there was a way to modify the folder structure on the Facebook and Facebook Messenger app to use the folders already set up in the Gallery to select photos, rather than selecting *all* at once and ordering them by "last modified".

To explain, I have several folders in my Gallery app - "Camera", "Facebook", "Friends" etc. When using the Facebook and Facebook Messenger apps, and I want to share a photo, I just get *all* of my photos, seemingly organised by the date they were last updated (including if the photo was edited).

So is there a way to get these apps to use the folder structure I have in my Gallery app, rather than the current setup?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this I know of is to circumvent facebook when selecting photos.

### To do this:

- go to your gallery
- select the photo(s) you want to send
- press share on those
- choose the method as facebook or messenger.

If you want I can explain in more detail, just comment if that's the case.